# Using Page $data variables in template

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Is there a way to use page $data variables in the template it's loaded in?

For instance - if I have a template that has a head like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
  <title><?php echo $data['title']; ?> | ACME, Inc.</title>
</head>
```

My view is pages/home and the controller looks something like this:

```
 public function index($data) {


$data = array();
            $data['title'] = 'Home';

        $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
}
```

How do I get a parent template or sibling view to take on the page's variables?

Comment: `<?php echo $data['title']; ?>` shouldn't it be `<?php echo $title; ?>`?

Comment: Where are you including the view with the header information?

Comment: Well, I have a page that uses a template. That template has a `head` view that I want to pass the page-specific var to.

Comment: Use `<?php echo $title; ?>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use the code below for meta data in page

**In controller:**

```
 $page = new stdClass();
        $page->title = "Your Page Title";
        $page->desc = "Your page description";
        $page->key = "keword1,keyword2,keyword3";
        $page ->author = "Alex";

 $data['page'] = $page;
 $this->load->view('pages/home', $data);
```

**In View:**

```
<title><?php
if(isset($page->title)){
echo $page->title;
}
?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php
if(isset($page->desc)){
echo $page->desc;
}
?>"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php
if(isset($page->key)){
echo $page->key;
}
?>"/>
<meta name="author" content="<?php
if(isset($page->author)){
echo $page->author;
}
?>"/>
content="<?php
if(isset($page->desc)){
echo $page->desc;
}
?>"/>
```

This is safe for not conflicting variable and easy to use.